# Read JPEG frame from MJPEG camera without decoding in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg, video-capture, mjpeg

I am writing an MJPEG video streaming application in Python on Ubuntu (headless). Depending on user inputs, I may or may not want to change anything about the frames captured from a MJPEG USB camera before streaming them to a webpage.

Currently, I'm reading the camera using OpenCV's VideoCapture() stream class. However, this wastes a lot of CPU/battery power converting the frame from JPEG to BGR array ( via VideoCapture().read() ) and back again when all I want to do is send the JPEG frame directly to the web page. Is there a way to read a frame from the camera as a JPEG without automatically decoding it? (This would also give me the chance to try TurboJPEG's JPEG decode instead of OpenCV's - its JPEG encode is a lot faster.)

Comment: Videocapture should has a set property to disable auto converting like ```videoCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)```. Also you can read streaming with ffmpeg to speed up and for effective cpu usage

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thank you so much! That works perfectly.