# how to turn off decoding of mjpeg stream from webcam in windows

Tags: opencv, jpeg, webcam, decoding, mjpeg

I am trying read full resolution JPEG frame (4k) from MJPEG camera without decoding in Python/OpenCV. i tried the method from this post  [Read JPEG frame from MJPEG camera without decoding in Python/OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664621/read-jpeg-frame-from-mjpeg-camera-without-decoding-in-python-opencv/70869738?noredirect=1#comment125294746_70869738)
but video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0) made no different.
I still get decoded frames. ("image type of frame1: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>" )

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 0)
video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, 
video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10.0)
video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 25920)
video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 19440)

if not video_capture_1.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera1")

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('dualcam.avi', fourcc, 30.0, size)

while True:
    video_capture_1.grab() 
    _, frame1 = video_capture_1.retrieve()  
    #print("frame1:", frame1.shape)
    print('image type of frame1:   ' + str(type(frame1)))

    if (ret1) :
        out.write(frame1)
        cv2.imshow('recording', frame1)
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break
video_capture_1.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

it did not work. very likely because window don't give you the trun off choice anymore. it started from 2016 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d6a8704-764f-46df-a41c-8e9d84f7f0f3/mjpg-encoded-media-type-is-not-available-for-usbuvc-webcameras-after-windows-10-version-1607-os?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment
also i coudnot use FFmpeg to connect to my webcam in windows.as windows use only directshow for usb webcam
anyway to get around?

Comment: `video_capture_1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)` Disables the conversion from YUV to RGB (probably from YUV420 to YUV). For disable decoding try using: `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)`, but I don't know what are you going to get. Why are you setting the resolution to `25920x19440`? `FFmpeg` may support your DirectShow for USB webcam. How do know it is not?

Comment: you'll still get a np.ndarray but **check its shape**. do you notice? it's just a bunch of bytes now.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no. the shape is still the same. i am using win10

Comment: @Rotem cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1) did not work. I still get the same image type and shape. I am using 2 k and 4 k usb cameras so by setting a very high resolution, i can get the full resolution of the camera. I installed FFmpeg and tried video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG), but then video_capture_1.isOpened() is false and the size of the image become (0,0).

Comment: I thought about trying FFmpeg command line tool (not `cv2.CAP_FFMPEG`). You may start [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow). `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`. Note: I don't understand what you are asking. Please clarify the meaning of "turn off decoding".

Comment: @Rotem my task is actually simple, i have a 4k usb camera, usb2.0, outputs mjpeg video stream at 30 fps. and i want to stream it online or save it into file. so there is no need to decode it.

Comment: Is the camera listed when executing `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` from command line? (you have to download FFmpeg first - you may follow the [instructions](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows)).